# Install / add nodejs into (Jenkins) docker image permanently

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins

How can I (best) install/add nodejs permanently into a (Jenkins) docker image?

The result is a docker image with both Jenkins and nodejs.

The purpose is to install nodejs as a Global Tool in the Jenkins container. To achieve the **installation folder of nodejs** has to be known.

I saw e.g. this solution, but what is the installation folder of Nodejs?

> RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash && \
>       sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

Adding nodejs (later) automatically at Jenkins build time is not a good thing, because it slows the build process down.

Comment: Why can't you simply use the [`docker-node`](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node) image?

Comment: I have already have a Jenkins image in which I can access Docker. I added maven to it to run maven jobs. Now I finally would like to add nodejs to the Jenkins image. Why? Then I can use nodejs as a global tool inside Jenkins. So how can I add nodejs to the Jenkins image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing nodejs on top of the jenkins image is the way to go. Adding an instruction to install nodejs inside the Dockefile is a standard thing in Docker to do when packaging dependencies.

> Adding nodejs (later) automatically at Jenkins build time is not a
>   good thing, because it slows the build process down.

This is not always true. Docker builds use a cache for layers being created when building a Dockerfile. Thus if you install nodejs at the top of your Dockerfile, you will only have to wait once for the installation and the next build commands will just use the cache and there won't be any additional time required to install nodejs inside the Jenkins image.

I would recommend that you install nodejs inside the jenkins image using [docker multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). Since there already exists a [Docker image for node](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/), you can use that to install node inside the jenkins image.

```
FROM node as nodejs

FROM jenkins/jenkins
COPY --from=nodejs /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
```

By building the Dockerfile above, you will get an image with jenkins and node installed using the official node Docker image.

Comment: Thank you! Can I use /usr/local/bin/node as the nodejs installation folder within the Jenkins global tool  action?

Comment: This method works but it doesnt install npm
COPY --from=nodejs /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm
Tried this but still npm wont work

Answer (score 1):

Besides the answers, please have a look to this [superb solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52413597/3143823). This allows install nodejs and npm. Now I can run 'npm' as a command in the shell. So, no need of the Global Tools usage is needed. Notice: it suggesets that using multiple FROM's is not a good practice (any more).

A very good addition is [this piece of advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52413590/3143823). If you need multiple node versions, you can also define them in your Jenkinsfile!

Answer (score 0):

If you see this there is a better way. The only reason you should use the other solutions is if you REALLY REALLY need node installed on your jenkins docker for use outside of a jenkins.

If you are using node for a build see this plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs

Follow the instructions there and you will have node working in your build in a matter of minutes