# Dockerfile: add npm to an existing docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm

Having a Jenkins Docker image, I would like to add the complete 'npm' environment to that image. So after building the Dockerfile I have an image with both Jenkins and the 'npm' environment.

The purpose is that a Jenkins job to run the shell command 'npm'. So 'npm' should be on the $PATH (in Ubuntu).

I have already a Dockerfile with a lot stuff in there like Jenkins and Maven.

A solution for node was described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52271351/3143823). The important thing is, can I do something simular? Which folders should I copy to the Jenkins docker image?

```
FROM node as nodejs

FROM jenkins/jenkins
// All kinds of other stuff goes here
COPY --from=nodejs /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node ???
```

Installing 'npm' automatically within a Jenkins Global tool is not my preferred solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using multiple `FROM` directives [is not a feature, it's a bug](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14412#issuecomment-118995461). It's proposed to remove it and you should avoid using it at all costs!

If you need npm in your jenkins, just install it there. It's based on `openjdk` image anyway.

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

RUN apt-get install -y curl \
  && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash - \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs \
  && curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: Wait, using `FROM xxx AS yyyy` is **NOT** a bug, it is usable: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#use-multi-stage-builds

Answer (score 2):

I went into the same problem some time ago. In my case it turned out that it is better to use a throw-away containers with proper volumes instead of using a installed node/npm in the container with Jenkins.

Why? It turned out that many different version of npm have been used across the time. Setting up two versions of npm is possible of course (take a look at https://github.com/creationix/nvm) but the best solution I've chosen was that: https://getintodevops.com/blog/the-simple-way-to-run-docker-in-docker-for-ci.

However, please take notice that it was my case with my projects. I used docker inside the Jenkins container so that it was possible to use anything by using a job configuration (or later - Jenkinsfiles).

Comment: Yes, I understand this. And will keep this in mind when using multiple versions. Thank you +1.

Comment: Multiple version is one thing. Second one - keeping Jenkins container as simple as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I did try the @kevin-kopf, but after that, the
`yarn -v` was giving the following error:

`ERROR: There are no scenarios; must have at least one.`

Finally, I did fix my problem like this (inspired by the same solution):

```
RUN apt-get install -y curl \
  && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs \
  && curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh

# Add Yarn
RUN npm install -g yarn
```